# SMTP Email Format to Full Name

Tags: asp.net, outlook

We have created an asp.net application now the application sends email using smtp, sending email is ok but as we received it on outlook we are received it as name.lastname@company.com and not the Full Name (James Reign). Please help me, below are my code snippets.

```
<system.net>
<mailSettings>
  <smtp from="lastname@company.com">
    <network defaultCredentials="false" host="server" password="lalala" userName="James.Reign" />
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

---

```
Public Shared Sub SendEmailToITSupport(ByVal sender As String, ByVal receiver As String, ByVal subject As String, ByVal body As String) 
Dim mySMTP As New SmtpClient Dim oMail As New MailMessage(sender, receiver, subject, body) Try If System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("AllowSendingMail") = 1 Then oMail.IsBodyHtml = True mySMTP.Send(oMail) End If Catch ex As Exception Err.Clear() End Try End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

CS Code :

```
using(MailMessage message = new MailMesage(
        new MailAddress("You@Domain.com", "Your Name"),
        new MailAddress("Recipient@OtherDomain.com", "Their Name")
    ))
```

OR web.config

```
<smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="Mail Displayname &lt;mail@raccoom.net&gt;">
```

Comment: @Carisle i am already using this code and works fine for me.well, can you please share your code ??

Comment: You can add this code with your question also.Difficult to read this